# What is the error?Q-To determine and print the sum of the following harmonic series for a given value of n.(1+1/2+1/3+........+1/n)

Tags: c++, c, loops, c++11, for-loop

```
void main()  
{  
    int n,i;  
    printf("enter number");  
    scanf("%d",&n);  
    float s=0;  
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)  
    {  
        s=s+(1/i);  
    }  
    printf("sum is %f",s);  
}
```

I'm getting an output of 1.00. Why?

Comment: Because 1/2 is 0. int / int = int. int / float = fliat.

Answer (score -2):

Try this....

```
void main()  
{  
    int n,i;  
    printf("enter number");  
    scanf("%d",&n);  
    float s=0;  
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)  
    {  
        s=s+(1.0/i);  
    }  
    printf("sum is %f",s);  
}
```

if there are int/float then the expected result will be int. If you want the exact float result then you have to make float/float

Comment: Whilst correct, this needs some explanation. Also consider adding the small terms first.